# How change only one the most expensive product in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.Products
SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice - 10
ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC
```

and this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword `ORDER`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (That looks more like MS SQL Server syntax.)

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 2 (or more) products, with the same highest price.

Comment: Sorry i'm new. You have right it's MS SQL Server. I didnt think about what happend if there are 2 (or more) products, with the same price. My assumption is that there will be only one product. BTW its Northwind database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll do well to provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more than one product with highest price top will not server the purpose. Use common table expression instead. It will update all the products having highest price.

```
with cte as (
select * ,row_number()over(order by UnitPrice desc)ROWNUMBER from products
)
update cte set UnitPrice = UnitPrice -10
WHERE ROWNUMBER=1
```

If you want to do it with top then use subquery. (You can't use order by with update as you tried)

```
UPDATE dbo.Products
SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice - 10
where unitprice in (select top 1 unitprice from  dbo.Products ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks. Could u tell me why my query doesnt work? (Assuming there is only 1 product with highest price.)

Comment: You can not use order by directly with update statement. SQL Server doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery with `TOP`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice - 10
    FROM (SELECT TOP (1) p.*
          FROM dbo.Products p
          ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC
         ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MySQL remove the `TOP(1)`

```
UPDATE dbo.Products
SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice - 10
ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Limit is not for SQL Server.

Comment: Same error. 'LIMIT' doesn't work that's why i used 'TOP (1)'